# can't POST my form in express js application

Tags: javascript, express, post, ejs

I am trying to build my first app independently but I cannot go through that problem. I will be very grateful if someone helps me understand where the problem is. After click submit button I am getting an error Cannot POST /. I suspect that a mistake i trivial and this is annoying for me. In my opinion problem is in my route file.

Here is my `html form` (wrote in `ejs`):

```
<%- include('includes/start.ejs') %>

    <%- include('includes/navbar.ejs') %>
    <div class="container">
    <p>Here you can create your Tournament!</p>
    <form class="form" action="/" method="POST">
        <label>Discypline:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="discipline" placeholder="E.G. Chess"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Tournament type:</label><br>
        <select name="type">
            <option value="Bracket Tournament">Bracket Tournament</option>
            <option value="League Tournament">League Tournament</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <label>Description of Tournament:</label><br>
        <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
      </form> 


<%- include('includes/end.ejs') %>
    </div>
```

Here is my `route` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

const Tournament = require('../models/tournament.js')

router.get('/creator', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../views/creator.ejs');
});

router.post('/creator', (req, res, next) => {
    //const tournament = new Tournament()

    console.log(req.body.discipline);
    return;

});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my `app` code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');

const homeRouter = require('.//routes/home.js');
const creatorRouter = require('.//routes/creator.js');


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', homeRouter);
app.use('/', creatorRouter);

app.listen(3000);
```

Thanks for a help.
Best regards.

Comment: Fix the action of the form? like this: `<form class="form" action="/creator" method="POST">`

Comment: Thanks man. Big sorry for a problem :(